# Send Mail using SMTP in C++ on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, smtp

Can someone give me an example of how to send a mail using a C++ program? I have come across some programs but they are not that descriptive. I would also like to know what other libraries are there if I need more options.

Comment: do NOT depend on the URL `mailto`, that relies on your web-browser and email client, and here would be at best a hack job and at worst unreliable.

Comment: If you want to be really slick, learn how to write the commands over `Socket` to speak the SMTP protocol to the server.

Comment: Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58210/c-smtp-example for more answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might be interested in [libcURL](http://curl.haxx.se/).

It's a great multi-platform C library which supports a lot of different protocols, including SMTP.

The official web page contains samples and tips to get you started.

[Here](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/smtp-multi.html) is one that might help you.

Bindings exists for C++ (but I never used them) if you don't want to use the C interface.

Comment: cURL works great with c++. i have previous experience with it. But i never thought it could send mails.. :) thanks for your reply.

Comment: running  the pgm gives me this error :‘CURLOPT_MAIL_FROM’ undeclared and also this : ‘CURLOPT_MAIL_RCPT’

Comment: looks like i need to update libcurl to the latest version 7.21.2.... i have only 7.19.....

Answer (score 4):

You can use libquickmail, see: http://sourceforge.net/projects/libquickmail/
This simple library allows you to easily send e-mail from C/C++ with attachments and even using SMTP authentication.
It uses libcurl for the SMTP transport.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at VMime, native C++.  http://www.vmime.org/
Between the examples and the test suite, you should have everything you need.

Answer (score 1):

Since you added a linux tag to your question: A dirty way to send an email from a c++ program is to use the system command. You can find out how it works in any c++ reference. Then you just need to be able to send an email from the command line and you can do that (under linux) with the mail command or with mutt (if it is installed).