# Send emails from linux appication in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, email-client

I am doing an school assignment and i would like to send emails to gmail accounts.
I am creating a c++ application and how can i proceed. Do i need to install any lib or can i use a simple mailto: like in web applications. Pls advice.

Comment: Do not depend on the `mailto` URL prefix to help you in anyway here.  That's simply a queue to your browser to launch the write Email client and while there are some tricks to send that way with minimal interaction, your platform may not have this or the browser settings correctly.

Comment: If you want to be really slick I think you want to learn how to have your application speak SMTP over a `Socket` directly.  Take in settings for your application to have its own account

Comment: If it is for school, your will probably fail if you use mailto: as well :P ha ha

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58210/c-smtp-example

Comment: I tried the example stated above but my email is not sent to my gmail acount

Comment: FYI: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like the QT framework on linux to help you.

But you probably just need this: [Send Mail using SMTP in C++ on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458460/send-mail-using-smtp-c-linux)

Hope that helps,

~ Dan

Comment: I advise doing this if you know that your own port 25 is open (most internet service providers block theirs to avoid spamming) or you have access to a smtp server... such as one provided by emailing companies.

Comment: I accidently deleted some files in /etc/mail folder that belongs to sendmail and my send mail is not working properly. how can i install send from scracth

Comment: depends on what version of linux you are running.

Comment: sudo apt-get install sendmail

Comment: see this link for more info http://www.linuxserverhowto.com/linux-mail-server-sendmail/install-sendmail-using-apt-get.html